# python scipy.odeint: how to put arbitrary boundary conditions

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

i am trying to solve a second order ordinary differential equations using scipy.odeint.

The problem looks like:
f''(x) + g(f(x)) = 0. Where g is a known function of f(x).
I want to know f(x) on a certain interval [-d,0] and most importantly i want to define the boundary conditions for f(0) and f(-d)!

However, using scipy.odeint i only found a way to solve this equation by defining a set of fist order differential eq7uations, basically by:
y1 = f(x)
y2 = f'(x)

and thus:
y1' = y2
y2' = -g(y1)

I that form, as far as i know, the only way to define boundary conditions is to give values for:
y1(0) = initial_condition_01
y2(0) = initial_condition_02

So in principle (coming back to the second order differential equation) i have to define a boundary condition for f(0) and f'(0).

Is there anyway to define the boundary conditions by:
f(0) = x0
f(-d) = xd ?
So not to include the first derivative in the boundary conditions?

Comment: From the [fine manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html)  _"`solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y[, p, S, fun_jac, ...])` Solve a boundary-value problem for a system of ODEs"_ — Disclaimer: I never used `solve_bvp`

Comment: thanks a lot.
it worked! :)